# How can I move every other letter of a string to the left by one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is an example:

```
x = "Hello"
```

I want `y` to equal `Hleol`. So far I tried this:

```py
x = "Hello"
y = x[::-1]
```

But that just makes `y` backwards. How could I do this?

It probably has a bad title, which I am very sorry about.

Comment: Something like `x[0]+''.join([x[i+1:i-1:-1] for i in range(1, len(s), 2)])`

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Your problem statement is unclear: you say that you want to move "every other letter", but you move only the 3rd & 5th letters; the description would also require something for handling the 1st.

Also, you've shown no effort to deconstruct the problem on your own.  We expect this effort.

Comment: @yatu It starts from the first character, but you can't move it to the left because there's nothing to the left of the beginning.

Comment: You will need to dismantle the string into two substrings, then stitch it back together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You convert the string into a list. Strings are immutable but lists are good for index operations.

Then you ignore index 0 and switch contents of indexes 1 and 2, 3 and 4 etc up to max lenght of your string -1 so you do not get an index error at the end:

```
def wiggle_it(s):
    s = list(s)
    for i in range(1,len(s)-1,2):
        s[i],s[i+1] = s[i+1],s[i]

    return ''.join(s) # return list back joined as string

print(wiggle_it("Hello"))
```

Output:

```
Hleol
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop with increments of 2, and reverse the characters in each pair.

```
x = "Hello"
y = x[0]
for i in range(1, len(x), 2):
    chunk = x[i+1:i-1:-1]
    y += chunk
```

Comment: Chained slicing is not necessary there. Instead you can do `x[i+1:i-1:-1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the characters and only use the odd-indexed characters.

```
x = "Hello"
y = x[0]
for index in range(len(x)):
    if(index % 2 == 0 and index != 0):
        print(x[index])
        y += x[index]
        y += x[index - 1]
```

Comment: If you're looping on a range and only want the even values, use a step size of 2. If you want to skip 0, start at 3. Using a loop on `range(3, len(x), 2)` will make your `if` unnecessary.

Comment: That may be, but I just threw together a quick solution that works. What's the harm in having an extra if statement in such a short block of Python code?

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the string sliced in even and odd indices, but pad the sequences with an empty string on different ends to account for boundary conditions:

```
''.join(i for t in zip((*x[::2], ''), ('', *x[1::2])) for i in t)
```